# how to grab data from the comment tab from an online NYT article using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is a URL of an article from the New York Times: the URL containing the comment tab is http://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/04/world/asia/china-xinhua-donald-trump-twitter.html

It has a comment tab and I would like to grab all the comments from the website using BeautifulSoup lib of Python to achieve my goal.

Below is my code. But it yields empty result. I guess it is an issue of not telling the computer where exactly to find the source link. Anyone can modify it? Thank you!

```
import bs4
import requests
session = requests.Session()
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/04/world/asia/china-xinhua-donald-trump-twitter.html"
page  = session.get(url).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)
comments= soup.find_all(class_='comments-panel')
for e in comments:
    print comments.string
```

Comment: Have you looked at the page source at all using your browser's developer tools? You should be able to find the comments section quite easily.

Comment: don't you want `class_='comments-view')` or tab-content?

Comment: I would recommend trying a browser emulator, check [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org)

Comment: depperm: Thanks. but your advice gives the same result.

Comment: MattDMo - I tried to use Chrome's Inspect and look for the source of the comment section, as depperm said, I tried almost all the classes i.e. comments-panel, comments-view, etc. Each yields me the same result - empty!

Answer (score 1):

The comment tab with all comments is hidden and will be shown via a javascript event. As recommended by @eLRuLL you could use selenium to open the comment tab and retrieve the comments like this (here in Python 3):

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='.../geckodriver') # adapt the path to the geckodriver

# set the browser window size to desktop view
driver.set_window_size(2024, 1000)

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/04/world/asia/china-xinhua-donald-trump-twitter.html"
driver.get(url)

# waiting for the page is fully loaded
time.sleep(5)

# select the link 'SEE ALL COMMENTS' and click it
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.comment-count').click()

# get source code and close the browser
page  = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

comments = soup.find_all('div', class_='comments-panel')
print(comments[0].prettify())
```

EDIT:

To retrieve all comments and all replies to the comments, you need 1) to select the elements 'READ MORE' and 'SEE ALL REPLIES', 2) to iterate and to click them.
I've modified my code example accordingly:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver, common

driver = webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='.../geckodriver') # adapt the path to the geckodriver

# set the browser window size to desktop view
driver.set_window_size(2024, 1000)

url = 'http://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/04/world/asia/china-xinhua-donald-trump-twitter.html'
driver.get(url)

# waiting for the page is fully loaded
time.sleep(5)

# select the link 'SEE ALL COMMENTS' and READ MORE and click them
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.button.comments-button.theme-speech-bubble').click()
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.comments-expand.comments-thread-expand').click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException:
        break

# select the links SEE ALL REPLIES and click them
replies = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.comments-expand.comments-subthread-expand')
for reply in replies:
    reply.click()
    time.sleep(3)

# get source code and close the browser
page  = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

comments = soup.find_all('div', class_='comments-panel')
print(comments[0].prettify())
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin - Very smart solution and I modify a bit and it scrape the comments, but not all. There are hidden comments unless we click "read more".

Comment: Maybe, a more efficient alternative to scraping would be to use the NYTimes' [API](http://developer.nytimes.com/) which provides access to comments of registered users: http://developer.nytimes.com/community_api_v3.json#/Documentation/GET/user-content/url.json

Comment: Benjamin: I can see you have deep understanding of HTML, CSS, and JAVASCRIPT. 2 more questions: (1) Error occurs when I run your code, which alerts as "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (728, 817)
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)"  (2) for the css selector parts, how did you find the "button.button.comments-button.theme-speech-bubble''? Sorry I have little experience on web programming.

Comment: I've tested the extended version of the code this morning with the firefox geckodriver (due to different computer setting) - with the geckodriver it works fine - but I didn't change the webdriver in the post assuming that the chromedriver is working in the same way. This seems not to be the case. With the chromedriver I'm getting the same Error. At the moment I don't know what the problem is. Therefore, I've changed the webdriver to firefox geckodriver in the post. It should work this way.

Comment: Regarding your 2. question: right-button-cllick on the speech bubble icon in the article header -> inspect element, then chrome or firefox will show you the div tag with the class attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I was advised to use APIs. Figuring out the CSS class is time consuming and sometimes works awfully.